# Wordpress 3.5 + Foundation 5 not working on IE9

Tags: theme-development, customization, css

I'm using Wordpress with Foundation 5 to make a custom template. It works perfect on Chrome and Firefox, but grid attributes looks all broken on IE9 (styles and typography are working).
Is there any workaround to solve this? I have already tried to alternate JS calls between wp_head and wp_footer hooks with no success at all. Foundation 5 index.php that comes with download package from Foundation website works properly on IE9.

Comment: "Something is broken how can I fix it?" is not much of a trouble ticket. I'd suggest maybe updating WordPress before you spend more time on this. 3.5 is pretty old.

Comment: I know, but the ISP provider I'm working with only accepts this version. And no, I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using an approximately 2 year old version of WordPress
2. With what looks to be an up-to-date framework
3. that depends heavily on Javascript

[WordPress 3.5](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.5) shipped with jQuery 1.8.3. [This thread](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/436-using-jquery-1102-with-foundation-5) suggests that Foundation 5 is actually built for jQuery 2, but will will work with jQuery 1.10.2 (though one person still reports issues).

I am guess that you have a Javascript problem. IE9 is choking on some particular quirk of the jQuery or Foundation 5's scripts, or Foundation 5 is trying to use something not supported in the jQuery or scripts bundled two years ago with WordPress 3.5.

It sounds like you are trying to make old technology work with new, and that is going to be an uphill fight. You can certainly remove and replace the bundled scripts-- the script loader system makes that easy-- but I don't know if you can do that and not break other things. You could invert your problem-- get Foundation working but break Core scripts or other plugins. Remember that WordPress is written for *its* bundled Javascript. Change that and you are asking for trouble. The same with Foundation 5. If you can get this working at all, it probably means painstakingly hacking the script files. I have no idea how to be more specific than that.

*Maybe* that will help you move in the right direction.

Comment: I downgraded from Foundation 5 to 3, using the same configuration I worked on a previous project. My project has 3 Custom Post Types. I noticed that when I disable 2 of them, the layout doesnt break anymore. I simply cant understand why, since the CPTs are not using JavaScript.

Comment: Have you disabled Javascript to confirm that Javascript isn't involved?

Comment: I havent disabled it.... But their codes dont use JS to manipulate CPT custom fields.

Comment: I really dont have a single idea about what is happening. My previous project has 4 CPT and works perfectly. My current project is really simple, except that one CPT control events informations

Comment: Sorry, it has become pretty obvious that the problem is very localized and highly dependent on that theme. I will probably have to close it for those reasons.